# Outlook security prompt auto approval

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, outlook

I'm writing a function that will allow users to import their e-mails from outlook in to corporate storage. But I've encounter a problem with security promt, and since we still have clients with office 2003 we can't disable it.

I'm trying to autoclick it with this code:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);


    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int hwnd = 0;
        IntPtr hwndChild = IntPtr.Zero;
        while (true)
        {
            hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Microsoft Outlook");
            if (hwnd != 0)
            {
                hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Yes");
                if (hwndChild != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    SendMessage((int)hwndChild, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                    SendMessage((int)hwndChild, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
                else
                {
                    //...
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //...
            }
            hwnd = 0;
        }
    }
```

But when I'm trying to use that code I've encounter unexpected problem. Security promt will only disappear only when I'm actually performing mouse click no matter where even on some empty screen space. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Have you tried this code on another window? If it only fails on the security prompt, my guess is that it's by design to prevent defeating the prompt. If it doesn't work elsewhere, you have a starting point for debugging.

Comment: This could not be an answer, so I write only a comment. I have used [this tool](http://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) to bypass the outlook's security warning. At the time it was free but now, seems there are only a commercial license available. However I think you can still find the free version searching around.

Comment: @TimMedora Yes. It's working with anything else just fine. But I've seen tools in internet that can actually do that but they're not open source ofc and I can't use it in my project even if will buy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out MAPILab's Advanced Security for Outlook. Should also work for Outlook 2003. This will let you give a permanent access for your application - a pop-up window will show only the first time you access Outlook items:
http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/security/

Advanced Security will have to be installed on each machine you run your app. It's free for noncommercial and commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

You should [try using `SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx) and send <kbd>Y</kbd> for **Yes**.